# VWare Workstation 14 and new hostif.c on kernel 4.13 for fixing a memory error

Tags: vmware-workstation, kernel-module, memory-error

I'm running vmware 14.0 on Fedora 26/kernel 4.13

Everything works fine in kernel 4.12.
Since kernel 4.13, I can't start the VM, and the message relates to an "insufficient memory error".

I found a solution, which consists in a new (or patched) hostif.c (see [VMWare Workstation - not enough physical memory since last update](https://superuser.com/questions/1255099/vmware-workstation-not-enough-physical-memory-since-last-update/1257991#1257991))

I tried to compile vmmon with this new hostif.c, but it asks for a "vmmonInt.h"

I can't find vmmonInt.h in my vmmon.tar archive, nor on my system. So the new hostif.c can't compile.
I'm stuck with kernel 4.12, and can't upgrade my system.

Can you help me ? Where can I find this include ? Any idea ?

Best regards.

Comment: Check this guy's blog [here](http://rglinuxtech.com/?p=2039) (if you don't find it in that post itself then search around a bit).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found the solution here : [member Izzno] : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=230487